# emacs の helm-mini で バッファー一覧に *helm-ag-edit* バッファを表示する方法

Tags: emacs

emacs で helm を利用し、C-c b に helm-mini を割り当て、バッファー一覧表示を行っていますが、helm-ag で検索結果を編集モードにした時に生成される helm-ag-edit バッファーが表示されません。 ibuffer 等では全バッファーが表示されているのですが、 helm-mini（helm-buffer-list等）では表示されません。helm でのバッファーの表示する／しないの設定は変更できないのでしょうか？
以上、宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 原因

`helm-boring-buffer-regexp-list`で除外設定が行われているからだと思われます.
そちらの`helm-boring-buffer-regexp-list`が実際どういう値になっているか不明なので外れているかもしれませんが.

詳細はEmacsの`describe-variable`で見てもらえば分かるのですが,
デフォルトの値が

```lisp
("\\` " "\\`\\*helm" "\\`\\*Echo Area" "\\`\\*Minibuf")
```

と

```lisp
"\\`\\*helm"
```

を含んでいるため`*helm-ag-edit*`は表示されません.

このような設定になっているのはhelmは大量のバッファを作るのでそれを全部表示してしまうとバッファが多すぎて見づらいからだと思われます.

## 短絡的な解決策

短絡的な解決策としては`helm-boring-buffer-regexp-list`を`custom-set-variables`や`setq`で編集してしまい`"\\`\*helm"`を消す方法があります.
ただし,そうするとhelmの全バッファが見えて鬱陶しくなります.

## 少し踏み込んだ解決策

ホワイトリスト版の`helm-white-buffer-regexp-list`もあるので

```lisp
(setq helm-white-buffer-regexp-list '("helm-ag"))
```

などと設定してagだけは表示できるように出来ます.

Comment: helm-boring-buffer-regexp-list の内容をdescribe-variableで確認すると上記の通りの内容でした。
教えていただいた、helm-white-buffer-regexp-list を利用することで希望通りの動作となりました。ありがとうございました。